# How to you use list comprehension to match values from a two dimensional list to another two dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

For example i have two list that are two dimensional list

```
a=[[7,9,10,11,12],[4,11,14,16,21]]
b=[[5,9,14,15],[7,12,15,17,19],[8,14,15,17,19],[13,15,17,20,22]]
```

I would like the result to be

```
0. [[9],[12,7]]
1. [[4], [14]]
```

Copied from your comment:

for loop.

```
for idx,item_a in enumerate(a): 
    result = [] 
    for item_b in b: 
        result.append(list(set(item_a) & set(item_b))) 
    print(idx,result))
```

Comment: How would you do this with a for loop (or two)?  It's easier to suggest improvements to your code that to come up with something from scratch.  Oh, and creating two  lists with a list comprehension is a bit tricky (not impossible, but it involves an extra transpose like step).

Comment: I really don't want to use for loop because when i start a new line it only display the last row. But this is what i have for loop. for idx,item_a in enumerate(a): result = [] for item_b in b: result.append(list(set(item_a) & set(item_b))) print(idx,result))

Comment: `[[list(set(i)&set(j)) for i in b] for j in a]`

Comment: so what's wrong with the `result` (after the loop)?

Comment: The problem with the loop is that i cant use the display.  Sorry i am new to python

Comment: I used the loop you put in the comment the only problem is i cant see which index matches. Is there a way to use the index with the matching values kind of like what i put in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code is for you

```
res = list(enumerate([[list(set(x) & set(y)) for x in b] for y in a]))
# output: [(0, [[9], [12, 7], [], []]), (1, [[14], [], [14], []])]
```

As you can see, `res` is a list of tuples like: `(idx, list_value)`. 
For example `res[0]` contains the tuple `(0, [[9], [12, 7], [], []])` where `0` is the index and `[[9], [12, 7], [], []]` the list of the corresponding list of values. To remove all doubt, this is the code:

```
idx0, lst0 = res[0]   # or equivalently idx0, lst0 = res[0][0], res[0][1]
print('idx of res[0] is %d and the corresponding list is: %s' %(idx0, str(lst0)))
# output: idx of res[0] is 0 and the corresponding list is: [[9], [12, 7], [], []]
```

You can print all the results in this way:

```
for idx, val in res:
    print(idx, val)
```

And you will get:

```
0 [[9], [12, 7], [], []]
1 [[14], [], [14], []]
```

Comment: This works but there a way to put the index . Like the what have in the description for the results

Comment: I have updated the answer, now you also have the index associated with each list

Comment: Can you do this without the loop like a list comprehension

Comment: of course, it's already done without loops ... the loop only serves to print the results. I try to update the answer to make you understand better

Comment: @Chris88 I added more comments to my reply. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works the way i need it to. I really appreciate

Comment: I'm glad I helped you!  Please voteUp and mark my answer as the best.  Thanks :)

Comment: Hopefully i did it correctly.  Can u let me know if it worked